# How can I pass an external object to a YAML logging configuration file?

Tags: python, logging, formatting, yaml, smtplib

I am trying to set up an `SMTPHandler` in a YAML configuration file. Any time the script fails, I would like the logger to send an email to the person who started the script (e.g. `user_email`). Based on [PEP 391](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0391/#access-to-external-objects), I am trying to refer to that external object by prefixing `ext://` to the string I pass in.

```py
# config.yaml
version: 1
handlers:
  email:
    class: logging.handlers.SMTPHandler
    mailhost: ["smtp.office365.com", 587]
    fromaddr: "email@place.com"
    toaddrs: [ext://user_email]
    subject: "TEST"
    credentials: ["email@place.com", "password"]
    secure: []
    level: ERROR
loggers:
  __main__:
    level: INFO
    handlers: [email]
```

```py
# __main__.py
import yaml
import logging
import getpass

import logging.config
import logging.handlers

username = getpass.getuser()
user_email = f"{username}@place.com"

with open(r'./config.yaml') as cfg:
    config = yaml.safe_load(cfg)
    logging.config.dictConfig(config)

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

try:
    raise Exception()
except Exception:
    log.exception('Unhandled Exception')
```

When I run this code, I get an `smtplib.SMTPRecipientsRefused` error, which says:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jessenestler/anaconda3/envs/facilityid_env/lib/python3.7/logging/handlers.py", line 1020, in emit
    smtp.send_message(msg)
  File "/Users/jessenestler/anaconda3/envs/facilityid_env/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 967, in send_message
    rcpt_options)
  File "/Users/jessenestler/anaconda3/envs/facilityid_env/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 881, in sendmail
    raise SMTPRecipientsRefused(senderrs)
smtplib.SMTPRecipientsRefused: {'//user_email': (501, b'5.1.3 Invalid address')}
```

It looks like the // doesn't get stripped properly, but even when I write `toaddrs: [ext:user_email]` in my config file, I still get the same error, but it says `smtplib.SMTPRecipientsRefused: {'user_email': (501, b'5.1.3 Invalid address')}`.

How do I make my YAML config file accept the `user_email` variable so that it successfully sends an email? I'm in Python 3.7

Comment: Not sure if it works, but you could try either `ext://__main__.user_email` or define it in the logging namespace: `logging.user_email = f"{username}@place.com"`

Comment: @flyx neither of those suggestions worked. The first yields `smtplib.SMTPRecipientsRefused: {'//__main__.user_email': (501, b'5.1.3 Invalid address')}`, while defining the variable in the `logging` namespace and calling `ext://logging.user_email` inside the config gives a similar error.

Comment: I meant keeping the `ext://user_email` while putting the value into `logging` since this seems to be the environment in which the name would be bound. Anyway, the fact that `ext` gets stripped and `//` does not seems to be very strange.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how relevant this still is for you but I had the exact same bug.

Apparently the issue is from yaml's parser specially treating the "[ext:" character sequence. Simply strip the "[" character from that and leave it like the following:

toaddrs: ext://script_name.user_email

In which user_email is a global variable declared inside script_name.py

I think [ext: might be some special syntax from yaml's official specification or something. Really annoying

Comment: Now, what is your solution, exactly?

Comment: Solution: replace toaddrs: [ext://user_email]
 with toaddrs: ext://script_name.user_email (note the missing brackets)